# sparkRDD and large file comparison

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

Scenario: I've 85789142 JSON documents, and a textfile with 32227957 items.

The textfile would look like:

```
url1
url2
url3
```

And a sample JSON document:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","url":"some_url"}
```

I want to find the JSON documents corresponding to the items in the textfile.

What I've done:

```
import json
textfile_rdd = sc.textFile("path/to/textfile.txt")
urls = set(textfile_rdd.collect())
json_files_rdd = sc.textFile("path/to/the/directory/of/json/files")
json_rdd = json_files_rdd.filter(lambda x: (json.loads(x)).get("url") in urls )
```

This code works for a textfile of small size (I've tried with 500000 documents).

Currently I'm splitting my textfile of 32227957 into smaller files, are there any better approaches?

Comment: what's your cluster configuration ? is there any error ?

Comment: i'm running a single node . no errors, but is there any solution other than splitting the fiie ?

Comment: and ? that's enough information to understand the source of your problem !

Comment: so i need to add more nodes, and what should i do with the textfile ? 
as you can see i'm collecting the urls into a variable

Comment: it's not about adding nodes, your bottleneck is your driver, you are collecting all your textfile data into the driver. That's very bad practice. I know that you want to use the data-structure inside of an rdd and nesting rdds isn't possible. So the only solution would be to join both table on a key, otherwise it won't scale

Comment: do you have a code sample ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113482/discussion-between-eliasah-and-frank).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to parse your json file using sparkSQL and load the textfile as a DataFrame of one column too. Then you could simply join the two datasets, without any need to collect the first file to the driver, which is your scalability issue now...

Comment: hi mark, i managed to do that with RDD's itself. check this,
textfile_rdd = sc.textFile("textfile.txt").map(lambda x: (x,1))
json_rdd = sc.textFile("path/to/json/directory/").map(json.loads).map(lambda x: (x.get("url"),x))
output = textfile_rdd.join(json_rdd)

i'm not sure how to do this with dataframes !

Comment: Yes, it's fine the way you've done. DataFrame API is just a bit simpler and it's a bit more efficient. Anyway, the way you've done is definitely fine. With DataFrame reading a JSON is simply a sqlContext.read.json("filename"). Then you have a join method as you can see here (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html).